# Can instructions exist in sections other than text?

Tags: assembly, elf, disassembly

Is it safe to assume that all instructions within an executable are located inside that executable's text section? I have never seen an executable with a format that violates this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, code may be located in any section that is marked as such. Furthermore, code may be located in any section provided that the appropriate page will be marked executable at runtime, or if the code is copied to an executable page.

For example, even `/bin/true` has code in the `.plt`, `.init` and `.fini` sections in addition to `.text`.